# How to find a list of nodes by two conditions in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 3 kinds of nodes: tag, city and place.

I want to write a query which takes 2 lists

```
 [tag1,tag2,....]
```

and

```
 [city1,city2,....].
```

I want to find a list of places located in one of these cities and order them from the one has as much tags as possible to the ones with fewer tags.

```
 MATCH (spot:Spot)-[:located_at]->(city:City ) 
 where city.id IN ["22","23"]
 with spot as sp,city as cy
 MATCH (sp:Spot)-[rels:tagged_by]->(tag:Tag)
 where tag.id IN ["16", "10151", "21"]
 with sp as fsp, tag
 RETURN fsp, tag,    count(distinct fsp.id) AS cnt
 order by cnt desc
```

I tried that query and somehow could not list the nodes and their tags.

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: here is a useful link for doing jaccard index in neo4j http://neo4j.com/graphgist/49a2b9874b37b4a2da4a/

Comment: @TomažBratanič I am having trouble for having the nodes with their tags respecting that they are in these cities and all their tags are within these given tags. seems my above code is wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by the following. My mistake was not knowing to count relationships and not knowing proper using of aggregation.

```
 match (city:City)<-[]-(spot:Spot) 
 where city.id in ["22","23"] 
 match (spot)-[rel]->(tag:Tag) 
 where tag.id in ["16", "10151", "21"] 
 return spot, count(rel) as rel_count 
 order by rel_count desc limit 100
```

This worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try the subquery apporach:

Pick city - > find spots -> find tags for that spot

```
MATCH (city:City)
OPTIONAL MATCH (spot:Spot)-[:located_at]->(city) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (spot)-[rels:tagged_by]->(tag:Tag)
where city.id IN ["22","23"]
where tag.id IN ["16", "10151", "21"]
RETURN spot, tag, count(distinct fsp.id) AS cnt
order by cnt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would approach this problem is.

```
MATCH (spot:Spot)-[:located_at]->(city:City)
RETURN city,spot,size(spot-[:tagged_by]->()) as tags order by tags desc
```

so now you get all the spots with the most tags. Obviously you can add filters how you want

```
MATCH (spot:Spot)-[:located_at]->(city:City) where city.name = "London"
RETURN city,spot,size(spot-[:tagged_by]->())  as tags order by tags desc
```